# AWS emr driver jars

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to use external drivers in AWS EMR 5.29 on pyspark notebooks via:

```
#%%configure -f
{ "conf": {"spark.jars":"s3://bucket/spark-redshift_2.10-2.0.1.jar,"
                        "s3://bucket/minimal-json-0.9.5.jar,"
                        "s3://bucket/spark-avro_2.11-3.0.0.jar,"
                        "s3://bucket/RedshiftJDBC4-no-awssdk-1.2.41.1065.jar"}}
```

As per https://blog.benthem.io/2020/04/21/connect-aws-emr-to-spark.html

However, when trying

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = spark # existing SparkContext
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

df = sql_context.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")\
                                    .option("url", jdbcUrl)\
                                    .option("query","select * from test")\
                                    .option("tempdir", "s3://")\
                                    .load()
```

I get
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.redshift.

How can I troubleshoot this? I can confirm the emr role has access to the bucket as I can process a CSV file on the same bucket with spark.  I can also confirm all the listed jar files are in the bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the way to troubleshoot this is to SSH into the master node and then look at the ivy logs:

> /mnt/var/log/livy/livy-livy-server.out

and the downloaded jar files at

> /var/lib/livy/.ivy2/jars/

based on what I found out I changed my code to:

```
%%configure -f
{
    "conf": {
        "spark.jars" : "s3://bucket/RedshiftJDBC4-no-awssdk-1.2.41.1065.jar",
        "spark.jars.packages": "com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:2.0.0,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0,com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you include `spark.jar.packages` isn't `spark.jars` already brining those JARs for you?

Comment: @NebiMAydin You're right possibly only needed spark.jars.   However I'll keep then answer as this is how it worked.